# Mysql Auto_increment id number Order Missing

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-constraint, composite-primary-key, unique-key

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(
  id  int  auto_increment unique,
  user_id INTEGER, 
  content_id VARCHAR(10), 
  points  INTEGER, 
  content_type INTEGER, 
  description VARCHAR(100), 
  created_date DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, content_id, content_type)
)
```

I created the TableA, But the Problem is When I was instating the Record into TableA then Facing id Auto_increment Issue,

In the below table First, I added a unique pair Then id=1

After 2nd time I was trying to add the same Record then It throws error BCS of a combination of user_id, content_id, and content_type to be unique, I think it's working fine

For 3rd time, I added it differently Then it added it on the table But Id =3, My question is Why Id is missing and How to fix it, Can anyone help me out, Please

```
:id user_id, content_id, points, content_type, description, created_date: 
1    1        1a1           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:54
3    1        1a1           5        2              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
5    1        1a2           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:54
6    1        1a3           5        2              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
```

I want to insert the Records into a table with out Missing ID number Order, Like Below

```
:id user_id, content_id, points, content_type, description, created_date: 
1    1        1a1           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:54
2    1        1a1           5        2              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
3    1        1a2           5        1              null     2021-02-26 08:26:54
4    1        1a3           5        2              null     2021-02-26 08:26:56
```

Comment: This is a norma, don't worry about it. If you need enumeration without gaps then use additional column for this purposes and assign it programmaticallty, or enumerate in a query.

Comment: @Akina, Thanks For Your Time, And can you Give suggestion for how to write it with additional column by enumerate in a query

Comment: Is it possible that the rows will be inserted concurrently (from 2 separate sources/applications at the same time)? Does the rows may be deleted from this table?

Comment: It's somewhat bizarre to stick unique on the surrogate and primary on the composite; it's normally the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
-- add a column for enumeration
ALTER TABLE TableA
ADD COLUMN enumeration INT UNSIGNED UNIQUE;
```

```sql
-- create trigger which assigns enumeration values
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bi_TableA
BEFORE INSERT
ON TableA
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.enumeration = COALESCE(1 + (SELECT MAX(enumeration) FROM TableA), 1);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0119b35e59188a0ecec70fdec7fe4d41

If 2 concurrent processes should try to insert the same value at the same time then one of them will fail because of unique constraint violation. So avoid parallel inserts.